# how to combine xml layout and coding layout into one layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to combine java code layout and xml layout into one layout.

I have java code which shows visualizer for audio streaming. And i have xml layout so i want to combine both layout into one to display media control buttons and image bellow the visualizer layout.

Java code is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AudioFxDemoActivity extends Activity {

    //Here is your URL defined
String url = "http://vprbbc.streamguys.net/vprbbc24.mp3";

    //Constants for vizualizator - HEIGHT 50dip
private static final float VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP = 50f;

    //Your MediaPlayer
MediaPlayer mp;

//Vizualization
private Visualizer mVisualizer;

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private VisualizerView mVisualizerView;
    private TextView mStatusTextView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Info textView
    mStatusTextView = new TextView(this);

    //Create new LinearLayout ( because main.xml is empty )
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    mLinearLayout.addView(mStatusTextView);

    //set content view to new Layout that we create
    setContentView(mLinearLayout);

    //start media player - like normal
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(url); // set data source our URL defined
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    try {   //tell your player to go to prepare state
        mp.prepare(); 
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            //Start your stream / player
    mp.start();

    //setup your Vizualizer - call method
    setupVisualizerFxAndUI();        

            //enable vizualizer
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);

            //Info text
    mStatusTextView.setText("Playing audio...");
}

    //Our method that sets Vizualizer
private void setupVisualizerFxAndUI() {
    // Create a VisualizerView (defined below), which will render the simplified audio
    // wave form to a Canvas.

    //You need to have something where to show Audio WAVE - in this case Canvas
    mVisualizerView = new VisualizerView(this);
    mVisualizerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            (int)(VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
    mLinearLayout.addView(mVisualizerView);

    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
    //YOU NEED android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO for that in AndroidManifest.xml
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(mp.getAudioSessionId());
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false); 
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (isFinishing() && mp != null) {
        mVisualizer.release();
       // mEqualizer.release();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}

/**
 * A simple class that draws waveform data received from a
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture }
 */
class VisualizerView extends View {
    private byte[] mBytes;
    private float[] mPoints;
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();

    private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

    public VisualizerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mBytes = null;

        mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
        mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mForePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 128, 255));
    }

    public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mBytes == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
        }

        mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
        }

        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
    }
}
```

}

And XML is file which having buttons and other stuff i will add into XMl later.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:text="Reverse" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="play" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:text="forward" />
```

Comment: -1, What have you tried? Do you know `inflate` method?

Comment: @thelawnmowerman i know that inflate method can help..but in my case i dont know how to implement on this code and xml ..can you please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Split your VisualizerView layout and AudioFxDemoActivity layout into two separate classes.
Add all necessary constructors into VisualizerView class .
After that add something like that
`<your.package.with.VisualizerView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

in your layout. Also you can add listeners in your code or any customizations.
Feel free for questions =).